# How to use Angular2token to post name?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angular, devise

I have set up a device + rails api and created a registration component.
After creating a user and checking in the database the program has only committed the email and password even though I added the name and nickname in the form's fields.

**Rails console**

```
 User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 5, provider: "email", uid: "jj@jj.com", name: nil, nickname: nil, image: nil, email: "jj@jj.com", created_at: "2017-09-14 00:48:13", updated_at: "2017-09-14 00:48:14">
```

**Register component ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Angular2TokenService, RegisterData } from 'angular2-token';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent {

registerData: RegisterData = <RegisterData>{};
output: any;
  constructor(private _tokenService: Angular2TokenService) { }



  onSubmit() {

  this.output = null;

  this._tokenService.registerAccount(this.registerData).subscribe(

  res => {
  this.registerData = <RegisterData>{};
  this.output       = res;
  }, error => {
  this.registerData = <RegisterData>{};
  this.output       = error;
  }
  );
  }

}
```

**Register component html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
    <ul>
      <li>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required [(ngModel)]="registerData.name">
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required [(ngModel)]="registerData.nickname">
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required [(ngModel)]="registerData.email">
</li>
<li>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required [(ngModel)]="registerData.password">
</li>
<li>
<button type="submit">Register</button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails we have strong parameters so please

Add following line to your application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?
  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :nickname, :email, :password)
    end
  end
```